# How to get the maximal signal number on a posix-compatible way?

Tags: posix, glibc

On Linux I've found

```
#define _NSIG            64
```

in `asm-generic/signal.h`, but I think including that wouldn't be a really standard-compliant solution.

`signal.h` in the glibc uses this `_NSIG` definition, but it hides behind a complex structure of include-define-undef-ifdef and similar preprocessor commands, and it isn't a visible symbol after a simple `#include <signal.h>`.

I am simply looking for a way to find the maximal signum I can give to `sigaction` and similar signal handling api calls, including the realtime signals. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: POSIX.1-2001 requires `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX` to be defined and that an implementation support at least `_POSIX_RTSIG_MAX` signals. Use these definitions instead

Comment: @JensMunk _POSIX_RTSIG_MAX resolves to 8 (!!) in `bits/posix1_lim.h` of the glibc, while the real value on my system is 64. Maybe it is some signal queue size or similar thing. `SIGRTMAX` is also undefined after a `#include <signal.h>`, with the similar problems as I experienced with NSIG.

Comment: That is the minimum number of signals required to be POSIX compliant. The current number of signals is given by SIGRTMAX. You may need to give your compiler an option to expose SIGRTMIN, check the headers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The POSIX.1-2001 standard requires the definition of `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX`. On linux they are defined using _NSIG.

To be POSIX compliant, use the above definitions instead of directly using `_NSIG`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
  printf("%lu\n", SIGRTMAX);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints 64 on my system when compiled using `gcc main.cpp`

Comment: No, _NSIG, SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX are all invisible after a `#include <signal.h>`. They are defined in the headers, but are also hidden behind a complex structure of preprocessor commands. Either I didn't include something which isn't described by the docs I could find with google, or the glibc isn't posix-conformant.

Comment: On my system they are perfectly visible. Try compile the above and see that it prints 64. Maybe you have defined `_SIGNAL_H` in some other header preventing the definition to be read. Just a guess

Comment: You have right, thank you! It was a syntactic problem in my c++11 code. :-) (You will get your ups after midnight :-) ). NSIG, _NSIG and SIGRTMAX are all visible and work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX does not provide the maximum signal number. The last proposal to add NSIG to POSIX seems to have failed.

From http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1138, May 2017:

> **joerg:** For making portable shell implementations easier, it would be a good idea if the standard also adds a "NSIG" definition that may redirect to a getconf() call.
>
> **kre:** NSIG is not useful unless we also make assumptions about the values used for the signal numbers, like that they are from 1..NSIG which the standard avoids doing (and should continue to do.)

It's not POSIX, but many programs assume that signals go from 1 to some maximum number.  [Matz's Ruby uses this C code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/595af866bb46db24274dc26fb9b4d3af84fd0af5/signal.c#L72):

```
#ifndef NSIG
# define NSIG (_SIGMAX + 1)      /* For QNX */
#endif
```

[4.2BSD defined NSIG](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.2BSD/usr/man/man3/psignal.3) in signal.h, such that NSIG - 1 is the maximum signal number.  I guess that most other POSIX systems took NSIG from BSD, though NSIG was never part of POSIX.  Ruby runs on many POSIX systems and needed only these 3 lines for systems without NSIG.